# Why are these two sets of functions the same? Involves quasi-everywhere inequalities.

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, potential-theory

We have a smooth bounded domain $\Omega$, and sets $A$, $B$ and $A^+$ such that $A=A^+ \cup B$ with $B$ a set of capacity zero. (See below for what these sets are precisely).

Let $$S=\{ v \in H^1_0(\Omega) : v \geq 0 \text{ q.e. on $A$ and } v=0 \text{ a.e. on } A^+\}$$

Apparently, it is possible to say that in fact
$$S=\{ v \in H^1_0(\Omega) : v = 0 \text{ q.e. on $A$ }\}$$
but I don't see why. Can someone explain?

All I see is that $v =0 $ a.e. on $A$, because $B$ has capacity zero (and hence Lebesgue measure zero).

Here, q.e. means quasieverywhere (i.e., everywhere except on a set of capacity zero).

---

**If it helps**:
In my case, $A= \{u = 0\}$, $$B=\{u = 0\} \cap \{-\Delta u -f =0 \}$$ and $$A^+ = \{u=0\}\setminus \{-\Delta u -f = 0\},$$ where $u \in H^1(\Omega)$ with $f, \Delta u \in L^2(\Omega)$ and $-\Delta u -f \geq 0$ a.e. on $\Omega$.

---

Comment: It does not make sense to say that the capacity of $B$ is zero, because it involves the zero-level-set of $-\Delta u - f$ and this is only determined up to *measure* zero. Where did you found these claims?

Comment: @gerw Yes you're right. I came upon this as follows: in this paper,
(https://www.esaim-cocv.org/articles/cocv/pdf/2012/02/cocv110009.pdf) see Remark 2.5, they claim this when $B$ is "empty" (but they don't specify in which sense q.e or a.e.), and I have it from a good source that empty in the sense of lebesgue is not enough and that capacity is required.

Comment: @gerw see also https://www.math.hu-berlin.de/~hp_hint//content/hs16.pdf, the box at the bottom of page 10 and the paragraph after

Comment: I see. However, it does not make sense to speak about the capacity of a set which is only defined up to measure zero. You need a more precise definition of your set $B$, see, e.g., the appendix of https://doi.org/10.1137/130925827.

Comment: @gerw Great. Thanks